# Isekai manga where gamers were summoned by god, but one person refused to join them and went solo

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I only remember like first chapter of the manga, so can't give many details.

Many people who played an RPG were summoned by some god to complete mission(s) in another world. They were separated into groups but one boy refused, because he felt that something wasn't right. He was still sent to the other world.

Later on, at one point people he met told him, that his white robes were old-styled and no one wore them anymore. I also remember that he used magic to clean up his room and clothes.

Comment: Do you remember any other details? For example, why the one person went solo, what (if any) powers the summonees were given, or their goal? There are probably multiple existing manga with the basic premise of "multiple people summoned, one refuses", and definitely tons with "multiple people summoned, one is excluded"

Comment: Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "refusal"? It sounds like he's still taken to the other world. Did the god offer him some "cheat" skills that look amazing at first glance, but come with some drawbacks? Or was he taken to a different part of the world by himself? You mention white robes - was he a healer or saint?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @qazmlpok - I'd say that *in conjunction* there's enough info here to have a stab at uniquely identifying this. I count thirteen pieces of information: Isekai/RPG theme/groups of RPG game players summoned / summoned by a god/told they have to complete missions/separated into groups/one person refused/refuser was a boy/he wears robes/told they're old-fashioned/magic exists/MC is a magic-user/MC uses magic to clean things.

Comment: @Valorum Yes, I'd agree it should be reopened as-is. That was a specific query, because the question now makes me think of two different series I've read that have a "refusal" of sorts. I'm guessing it's one of those, but I'd need to track them down to verify.

Comment: @qazmlpok - It's very tropey, but then that's true for almost all Manga these days. There is, as they say, nothing new under the sun

Comment: To LogicDictates, I don't remember. To qaz, Refused as didn't join any of the team, but was still sent to another world. To Valorum, that's the problem. It has some certain plot points, but I still can't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is probably *[Gokufuri Kyohi Shite Tesaguri Start! Tokka Shinai Healer, Nakama to Wakarete Tabi ni Deru](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/gokufuri-kyohi-shite-tesaguri-start-tokka-shinai-healer-nakama-to-wakarete-tabi-ni-deru)*.

> **Many people suddenly find themselves in a white, empty space, where a God-like figure tells them that they are to be reincarnated and sent to an isekai known as Tesla**. They are given a limited number of points to spend in various attributes, such as their race and abilities, which will determine their reincarnation into Tesla. Follows a young boy **sent there along with his clanmates from an MMORPG**, and they plan to stick together and specialize into different skills, just like they did in-game. Although his clanmates and everyone else sent there are strangely accepting of the situation, he finds it too suspicious and **decides to go his own separate way**, balancing his points out to be an all-rounder instead of a healer. He leisurely goes about life in Tesla as an adventurer, but it slowly starts to seem like there was a reason behind them being sent there...

Synopsis covers many of the points - it's an isekai where a god summons a large number of people, all of which were players of a game.

[image: Players of an MMO]   [image: Suspicious]

The god gives them a limited amount of time to think things over and allocate points - the main character finds the whole situation suspicious, but without enough time to talk it over with him guildmates, just goes off on his own.

I was not able to find the scene where he uses cleaning magic; I assume it takes place further in than I checked for this re-read. There was an explicit mention of general "household" magic, however. Other adventurers do comment on his use of a robe; he figured a magic user just needs to not wear any armor, but apparently not. This isn't quite "old fashioned", but it's the same general idea.

[image: Stereotypical white mage]

Comment: Yes. This is the one. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -3):

Could it be "Omniscient viewpoint" ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by editing it to explain why you think this might be the correct manga, i.e. the ways in which it matches the one described in the question. Copying and pasting a synopsis from a site like Manga Updates or My Anime List, along with a link to the relevant page, would be helpful too.

Comment: @Feronet, no it's not.